# Black patches appear on baked Normal Map

Tags: baking, shadows, normal-map

[image: weird patches]

I baked a normal map for my 3D model, but it seems it has some shading issues like black patches with sharp margin and different shades of grey on the two sides of a seam, there is a black patch under the groin around the inner thigh.

There is no stretching in the UVMap.

[image: there are no streching in the uv]

Is there any fix to these?
[image]

Comment: Hi! Can you add some more info about how you baked the normal map? High poly to low poly (Selected to active)? With cage? Have you adjusted the Max Ray Distance? Or did you the bake from a low poly model with multires modifier? The problem occures when the ray hits the opposite leg's surface first. A cage or a tweak of the Max Ray Distance could fix it.

Comment: High poly to lowpoly yes,without cage,yes max ray distance tweaking gave better result but it Couldn't fix the patching problem,no modifiers are active right now all are applied.